# Error build container from docker file when it runs mv command after download the symfony cli

Tags: docker, symfony5

I run make build command to create my docker container from the dokerFile but when the rutine downloads the symfony cli, it cant move the file to the usr/local/bin/symfony the error is the next one:

```
=> Error [11/14] Run mv /home/appuser/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
mv: cannot stat '/home/appuser/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony': no such file or directory
```

[image docker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIc3N.jpg)

I have tried to run the container but I couldnt due to this error

Comment: Could you add your dockerfile? it seems that mv command consider "/home/appuser/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony" as file to move, il could be a syntax error

Comment: Thanks lety for your soon answer,  

I found the error,  when doker executes the symfony cli installation, the symfony cli was in the next folder /home/appuser/.symfony5/bin/symfony 
my docker file had the following: /home/appuser/.symfony/bin/symfony. 

I am new user in stackoverflow do you know what i have to do with this answer?

Comment: you could write your answer for those who will encounter the same problem as your in the future.